# How to get all the text from the beginning of a 12 digit number and group them using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text in the below format but what I want is to select and group words from the beginning of the 12 digits found and stop at the beginning of the next 12 digit which should also be grouped together.

For instance, in my text below, the following should be grouped together:

> 011111111111   CDGH, LGF ADF      : 203 HYT    *LOREM IPSUM / LOREM
>   IPSUM* COUNTY   : GTYH       CHIDGER L. IPSUM THJ. DATE: 07/21/2000
>   LOREM IPSUM DOLOT & LOREM IPSUM      768 LOREM IPSUM, 67TH LOREM IPSUM
>   IPSUM. DTEA:            NIGER, GA 12345                        LOREM
>   IPSUM DOLOT                      97 LOREM IPSUM
>   DOLOT, KY 35678-8765

And also

> 0222222222222   CDGH, LGF ADF      : 203 HYT    *LOREM IPSUM / LOREM
>   IPSUM* COUNTY   : GTYH       johjk L. IPSUM THJ. DATE: 07/21/2000
>   LOREM IPSUM DOLOT & LOREM IPSUM      768 LOREM IPSUM, 67TH LOREM IPSUM
>   IPSUM. DTEA:            NIGER, GA 12345                        LOREM
>   IPSUM DOLOT                      97 LOREM IPSUM
>   DOLOT, KY 35678-8765

This is the sample of the entire document

> LOREM IPSUM                                           LOR IPSUM
>   DDDDDDDDD FG SSSSS                                   NUMBER
>   106/03/2019                                           LOREMFG GH
>   LOREMIPSUMF
>   LOREM OPFRTE ERTIO
>   LOREMIPS LOREMIOS   05/30/2019 DERTE TH LOREM (LWA
>   LTD)------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------011111111111   CDGH, LGF ADF      : 203 HYT    *LOREM IPSUM / LOREM IPSUM* COUNTY   :
>   GTYH       CHIDGER L. IPSUM THJ. DATE: 07/21/2000 LOREM IPSUM DOLOT &
>   LOREM IPSUM      768 LOREM IPSUM, 67TH LOREM IPSUM IPSUM. DTEA:
>   NIGER, GA 12345                        LOREM IPSUM DOLOT
>   97 LOREM IPSUM                     DOLOT, KY 35678-8765 0222222222222 
>   CDGH, LGF ADF      : 203 HYT    *LOREM IPSUM / LOREM IPSUM* COUNTY   :
>   GTYH       johjk L. IPSUM THJ. DATE: 07/21/2000 LOREM IPSUM DOLOT &
>   LOREM IPSUM      768 LOREM IPSUM, 67TH LOREM IPSUM IPSUM. DTEA:
>   NIGER, GA 12345                        LOREM IPSUM DOLOT
>   97 LOREM IPSUM                     DOLOT, KY 35678-8765 011111111111
>   CDGH, LGF ADF      : 203 HYT    *LOREM IPSUM / LOREM IPSUM* COUNTY   :
>   GTYH       CHIDGER L. IPSUM THJ. DATE: 07/21/2000 LOREM IPSUM DOLOT &
>   LOREM IPSUM      768 LOREM IPSUM, 67TH LOREM IPSUM IPSUM. DTEA:
>   NIGER, GA 12345                        LOREM IPSUM DOLOT
>   97 LOREM IPSUM                     DOLOT, KY 35678-8765

The code I have written only selects the 12 digit and the space but ignores the text between it. [Link to the regex101 I have written for this purpose](https://regex101.com/r/ZnGVH2/1)

```
(\b\d{12}\s*\b[A-Za-z0-9_.]*+\s+)
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? `\b(\d{12})\b[\s\S]+?(?=\b\d{12}\b|$)` https://regex101.com/r/RSa2kC/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 12 digits can also be on the same line you could use the start of your pattern with the word boundaries and use a non greedy quantifier with a positive lookahead.

If the values can span multiple lines and can occur at the same line twice you might consider using `[\s\S]+?` instead of `.+?`

```
\b\d{12}\b.+?(?=\b\d{12}\b|$)
```

In parts

- `\b\d{12}\b` Match 12 digits between word boundies
- `.+?` Match 1+ times any char except a newline non greedy
- `(?=\b\d{12}\b|$)` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is either 12 digits surrounded by word boundaries or the end of the string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1yGq6c/1)

Comment: This solved the problem but I ended up doing this (\b(\d{12})\b.+?)(?=\b\d{12}\b|$) because i need everything in a group Thanks this works